# Why doesn't JS and CSS show with my html file?

Tags: html, css

I started html and CSS today because I have to get my IT homework done. I have to make a simple restaurant menu but when I open my file it only shows the html one(im sure that css and js are written well, i think its a link problem). Sorry if it's obvious but im really new.

```
<html>
    <head>
<title>Jadłospis</title>
<link rel=¨stylesheet¨ type=¨text/css¨ href=¨menucss.css¨>
<script src="menujs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="group-header">
    <span>Tylko kanapka</span>
    <span>Zestaw</span>
  </div>

  <h3>
    <span>Hamburger</span>
    <span>10</span>
    <span>15</span>
  </h3>
  <p>Kanapka z kotletem z mięsa wołowego</p>
  <h3>
    <span>Cheeseburger</span>
    <span>11</span>
    <span>16</span>
  </h3>
  <p>Hamburger z dodanym żółtym serem</p>
  <h3>
    <span>Burger Hawajski</span>
    <span>13</span>
    <span>18</span>
  </h3>
  <p>Hamburger z ananasem, szynką i serem</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Right-click on the page, open the browser inspector, look at the Network tab. See if they're even found. Also, your quotes look wrong `¨`

Comment: well, first, those don't look like quotations surrounding your `href`. Secondly, is there a file in that path on your computer?

Comment: Can you provide a description of where youre css and js files are located in respect to the html file above?

Comment: They are in the same folder

Comment: Okey, it was a problem with the href i think. I copied it from a site and didn't see it changed the quotes

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be weird symbols on your `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menucss.css">` instead of `""` you have `¨¨`. If that is not the problem you should edit your answer and include your css file.

Comment: Solved, it was because of the href. I copied it from a site and got these instead of ". Thanks anyways!